# Invalid expression term '&&'

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public void Update()
    {
        AmmoAll();
        GetComponents();
        if (OnClickShoot()) && Time.time > _nextFire)
        {
            _nextFire = Time.time + 1f / fireRate;
            AmmoCheck();
        }
        if (_maxAmmo == true)
        {
            if (OnClickReload())
            {
                StartCoroutine(AmmoSize());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: У вас открывающих скобок меньше, чем закрывающих.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка тут:

```
if (OnClickShoot())
                  ^----
```